# ajax post in laravel 4 is not working properly not returning any value

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Hello here is my route (added to routes.php) :

```
Route::post('tsearch',array('before'=>'csrf',function(){
   // $data = Input::all();
   if(Request::ajax())
    {
   echo "hello";

   }

}));
```

then you have the form:

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm">
<input   placeholder="e.g photography"  type="text" class="form-control">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="tok" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Go!</button>
</span>
</div>
```

and  here is the javascript :
var kword = "testing";
 var token = $(this).data('token');

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/tsearch",
  data: { keyword: kword}
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    $('#results').html( msg );
  });
```

when I inspect it looks like the value testing gets passed but nothing is returned back.its not a 404 error, it finds the file it just doesnt return the echo that I have inside the route. I must be doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have a CSRF filter `'before' => 'csrf'`, and you don't send CSRF protection token with your POST-request. Try sending a token with your request.

Comment: still think it has something to do with csrf, try removing this `before` section whatsoever.

Comment: it ended up being the URL. so lame. thanks Twistar for your help